# Sort divs by ID in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to sort divs by ID in Javascript. So far, I've got an array of divs split into "leftSlide" and "rightSlide". I'm doing it like so:

```
var leftSlides = [];
    var rightSlides = [];
    $(".ms-left").find("div").each(function(){ leftSlides.push(this.id); });
    $(".ms-right").find("div").each(function(){ rightSlides.push(this.id); });
```

And my console output is:

```
// Left Divs
["slide0", "slide1", "slide2", "slide3", "slide4", "slide5", "slide6", "slide7", "slide8", "slide9", "slide10"]

// Right Divs
["slide-right0", "", "slide-right1", "", "slide-right2", "", "slide-right3", "", "slide-right4", "", "slide-right5", "", "slide-right6", "", "slide-right7", "", "slide-right8", "", "slide-right9", "", "slide-right10", ""]
```

Now I want to re-order my divs so they go something like this:

```
<div id="slide0"></div>
<div id="slide-right0"></div>
<div id="slide1"></div>
<div id="slide-right1"></div>
<div id="slide2"></div>
<div id="slide-right2"></div>
```

...and so on.

I notice that there's an errant empty div in the "slide-right" divs, but it's probably ok for them to be ignored, and if not, I'll try to find some logic to not add them to the array if they're empty. For now just trying to sort properly.

Any tips?

Comment: "Sorting" is not the right term. probably "Reorganizing" since you're following a known pattern.

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming your slides will always have the same length on the left side and the right side and are ordered correctly you can use this code.**
Please specify if you could have any other case!

```
var leftSlides = [];
    var rightSlides = [];
    $(".ms-left").find("div[id]").each(function(){ leftSlides.push(this); });
    $(".ms-right").find("div[id]").each(function(){ rightSlides.push(this); });

    $all = $(".all");
    for (var i=0; i<leftSlides.length; i++) {
        $all.append(leftSlides[i]);
        $all.append(rightSlides[i]);
    }
```

This code selects only `divs`with an `id` and then iterates trough the `leftSlides` array and pushes the elements from both arrays into one, first left then right.

Answer (score 0):

***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/tisiya/7/edit?html,css,js,console,output)***

if you remove `"-right"` from `"slide-right0"` you'll get the matching pair `"slide0"`:

```js
$(".ms-right").find("div").prop("id", function(i, id){
  $("#"+ id.replace("-right","")).after( this );
}).end().remove(); // After all is moved remove the .ms-right element.
```

```css
div{
  padding:5px; margin:5px;
  background:rgba(255,0,0,0.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ms-left">
  <div id="slide0">0</div>
  <div id="slide1">1</div>
  <div id="slide2">2</div>
  <div id="slide3">3</div>
  <div id="slide4">4</div>
  <div id="slide13">13</div>
</div>

<div class="ms-right">
  <div id="slide-right0">r0</div>
  <div>no ID</div>
  <div id="slide-right1">r1</div>
  <div>no ID</div>
  <div id="slide-right2">r2</div>
  <div>no ID</div>
  <div id="slide-right3">r3</div>
  <div>no ID</div>
  <div id="slide-right4">r4</div>
  <div>no ID</div>
  <div id="slide-right13">r13</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I have't try this code, just give you a tip.

```
var leftSlides = [];
var rightSlides = [];
$(".ms-left").find("div").each(function(){ leftSlides.push(this.id); });
$(".ms-right").find("div").each(function(){ rightSlides.push(this.id); });
$('#yourNewWrapper').html(function(){
    var allLeft = $('.ms-left').find('div');
    var allRight = $('.ms-right').find('div');
    var longLength = allLeft.length > allRight.length ? allLeft.length : allRight.length;
    var divHtmlCache = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < longLength; i++){
         var eachLeft = allLeft.eq(i).length ? allLeft.eq(i) : null;
         var eachRight = allRight.eq(i).length ? allRight(i) : null;
         divHtmlCache.push(eachLeft ? eachLeft.html() : '' );
         divHtmlCache.push(eachRight ? eachRight.html() : '');
    }
    return divHtmlCache.join('');
});
```

Answer (score -2):

You may try. I did not use any special function except for `$.insertBefore` for moving the elements as needed.

```
for(var x=0; x < $('div').length; x++)
{
    for(var i=0; i < $('div').length; i++)
    {
     if((i+1) < $('div').length)
        CompareDivs( $('div')[i], $('div')[i+1]);
    }
}

function CompareDivs(curr,next)
{
    var curr_idNum = $(curr).attr("id").substring($(curr).attr("id").length - 1,$(curr).attr("id").length);
   var next_idNum = $(next).attr("id").substring($(next).attr("id").length - 1,$(next).attr("id").length);
   if(curr_idNum > next_idNum)
   {    
     $(next).insertBefore($(curr));
   }
}
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/3h78pjkh/1/

Answer (score -2):

You could try something like this:

```
var leftSlides = [];
var rightSlides = [];
$(".ms-left").find("div").each(function(){ leftSlides.push(this); });
$(".ms-right").find("div").each(function(){ rightSlides.push(this); });

$all = $(".all");
for (var i=0; i<leftSlides.length; i++) {
  $all.append(leftSlides[i]);
  $all.append(rightSlides[i*2]);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/edoLtp1h/